# Material vs Pen in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I need to draw a lot of images in Asymptote with both a color & grayscale version.  Suppose I have a surface `s`. I have found that I like drawing `s` in color with

`draw(s,rgb(.6,.6,1)+opacity(.7),meshpen=rgb(0,0,.7));`

and in grayscale I like

`draw(s,emissive(white+opacity(.6)),meshpen=rgb(0,0,0));`.

I'd like to define a pen `mypen` that takes on one of two values depending on whether I'm in color or grayscale mode (set through a boolean variable). So my file would have just the one command

`draw(s,mypen,meshpen=p)`

where `mypen` is either defined by

`pen mypen=rgb(.6,.6,1)+opacity(.7);` or

`pen mypen=emissive(white+opacity(.6));` (and `p` is defined similarly).

My problem: while `rgb(.6,.6,1)+opacity(.7)` IS a pen, it turns out that `emissive(white+opacity(.6))` is actually a *material* and I can't define it using the `pen mypen=...` syntax. And it seems I can't define something like `material mymaterial=...`.

How can I define one variable to either be a pen or a material?

Comment: Have you tried `var mypen=...` ?

Comment: Or you can use `material mypen=rgb(.6,.6,1)+opacity(.7);` 
`material mypen=emissive(white+opacity(.6));`